# PHPMailer Character ñ on recipient address

Tags: php, email

I'm getting the next error on phpmailer when trying to send an email to a recipient address containing the letter "ñ", e.g.:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message
>   'Invalid address: lauro.muñoz@live.com.mx'

I know it says it is an invalid address, and it only because it contains the letter ñ, using `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` after `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`, doesn't work.

Any regular address without ñ work fine. Is there any way to make email addresses with ñ valid?

Comment: Have you tried using `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';` before `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Kinda hard to set a property on an object **before** it's created

Comment: @Phil I just realized that after; I stand corrected. Am Googling OP's issue now.

Comment: Double check to see if your PHP code is also in UTF-8 encoding and that (`$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';)` is not placed after `$mail->Send();` some have done that, from what I've found - Show full code.

Comment: Seems to be a failing in PHPMailer itself. Its [`ValidateAddress`](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L874) method is not unicode safe

Comment: I didnt know that `ñ` was a valid char in the addresses mail, good catch

Comment: Regex validation of email addresses is doomed to fail as it's attempting to hit a moving target. Perhaps try a more mature emailer like http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Bug raised ~ https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/251

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a library. A bug report has been raised so, short of recommending a different library there is no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that those kind of chars aren't allowed to be part of the "local part" of the email address http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Local_part.

Comment: If providing answer you can add more relevant details here from the link, else you can post this as a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Comments below your question suggest that your mailer does simply not support internationalised email addresses. If that's the case, the workaround you can use is to convert the address to its plain US-ASCII equivalent. The encoding used for that is called **punycode**. [For instance](http://www.charset.org/punycode.php?decoded=lauro.mu%C3%B1oz%40live.com.mx&encode=Normal+text+to+Punycode#results):

```
lauro.muñoz@live.com.mx
```

... becomes

```
lauro.xn--muoz-hqa@live.com.mx
```

... which should be exactly the same mailbox.

*Disclaimer: I've never worked with internationalised addresses, please test thoroughly.*