# Javascript Regex validate email with ñ character

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

Some time ago I posted this question [PHPMailer Character ñ on recipient address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521354/phpmailer-character-%C3%B1-on-recipient-address) and got my answer. Still, I decided to keep using PHPMailer, and I can't do anything about the ñ but exclude emails with the ñ character, I validate the email first with javascript using this regex I found somewhere in this site long time ago, which works pretty much fine, but I want it to also exclude emails with the character ñ.

I have a hard time understanding regex, once I found a very good explanation here on stackoverflow, but I lost the link. Anyway, here is my function I use to validate emails:

```
function isEmail(email){
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
}
```

To exclude ñ, I thought I could do it like this:

```
function isEmail(email){
var re = /^(([^ñÑ<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
}
```

Which works for emails like lauromuñoz@mail.com, BUT if I add a dot between name and last name, like this, lauro.muñoz@mail.com, it becomes valid.

**How do I fix the regex to catch ñ at any place in the email?**

Comment: I want it to be invalid, I want lauromuñoz@mail.com and lauro.muñoz@mail.com to have the same result. If you type lauromuñoz@mail.com it has no matches, I want lauro.muñoz@mail.com to have to matches ethier.

Comment: You said that you don't want to match the emails which has `ñ` in their names or in anyother part.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression is uneasy on the eyes and I would recommend parsing with a different tool. Somewhat of a solution for this would be to add Negative Lookahead after the beginning of string `^` anchor preceding your pattern.

```
var re = /^(?!.*[ñÑ]) ... $/
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wG4hZ0/2)