# How to send php mail with international recipient

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, webmail

How to send php mail with international recipient?

for example: How to send email To **δοκιμή@παράδειγμα.δοκιμή** with php mail function or PHPMailer?

Can i convert Local Part + server part of unicode email address to IDNA and then send email with php?

Is there a free service that offers international Email Address?!

Similar Threads:

[PHPMailer Character ñ on recipient address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521354/phpmailer-character-%C3%B1-on-recipient-address)

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/251

https://gmail.googleblog.com/2014/08/a-first-step-toward-more-global-email.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Unicode in the local part (the bit before the `@`) requires support for the SMTPUTF8 SMTP extension, which *is* supported by gmail, And various other mail servers, including postfix.

At present, no, you cannot make use of this with PHPMailer (though it is planned), and as far as I’m aware, no other common PHP email libraries support this either.

You *can* use IDN for Unicode domains (after the `@`), because it has a mapping to ASCII, and PHPMailer *does* support that. However, I’m not sure that IDN can be used for top-level domains yet, so I don’t think the domain example you gave will work.

Comment: Can I use the mail function to send an email to the following address (Local part=utf8) + (domain name convert to IDN) + (top-level domain=COM): 
δοκιμή@xn--hxajbheg2az3al.com

Comment: You may be able to get that to work by calling `mail()` directly (assuming it just passes through what you give it); PHPMailer will not let you do that as it will fail address validation before you get to sending. The most difficult part of supporting SMTPUTF8 is not in allowing this stuff through, it's dealing with downgrades when you connect to a server that doesn't support it, as described in [RFC6857](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6857). I'd be interested to know if you can make it work.

Comment: You shouldn't even try to downgrade when *sending* mail, that turned out to be such a bad idea that it was removed before 6530/…/6857 were published. Nice theory, bad practice. 6857 is about downgrading while reading, not for sending. It caters to the case where the receiving IMAP server supports EAI and the user uses several IMAP clients, one of which does not support EAI. It lets the user read a degraded version of messages using the non-EAI IMAP client, without the ability to reply. AFAICT noone has implemented 6857. I implemented 6858.

Comment: So what do you propose for send-time SMTP downgrade? If you don't have the ability to downgrade, it renders SMTPUTF8 entirely useless.

Comment: If send-time downgrade is to work usefully, then the receiver has to have an ASCII address, ie. this limits SMTPUTF8 to humans who can read and write latin letters. This is what the first set of RFCs did, and it worked badly. Better to not have any send-time downgrade, so the second set of RFCs basically say that if you can't send the mail as intended, you fail and return an error message.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me at a reference for that deprecation?